# ImageReader.getPlanes() returns Exception: RGBA override BLOB format buffer should have height == width

Tags: android

i am using ImageReader to take screenshot of Android device from service.
but *imageReader.planes* returns *AndroidMediaUtils: RGBA override BLOB format buffer should have height == width*.

My Code:

```
fun takeScreen() : ByteArray? {
    var result = byteArrayOf()
    val display = (getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager).defaultDisplay
    mediaProjection.registerCallback(object : MediaProjection.Callback() {}, null)

    val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
        display.width, display.height,
        ImageFormat.JPEG, 2
    )

    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    display.getMetrics(metrics)

    val flags = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY or DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC

    mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay( "vd", display.width, display.height, metrics.densityDpi, flags, imageReader.surface, null, null)

    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({
        val image = it.acquireLatestImage()
        if (image != null) {
            val planes: Array<Image.Plane> = image.planes
            val buffer = planes[0].buffer
            val pixelStride: Int = planes[0].pixelStride
            val rowStride = planes[0].rowStride
            val rowPadding: Int = rowStride - pixelStride * it.width

            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                it.width + rowPadding / pixelStride,
                it.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )

            bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream)
            result = stream.toByteArray()
        }
    }, null)
    return result
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved by changing *ImageFormat.JPEG* to PixelFormat.RGBA_8888.

Comment: this should be accepted as answer it solved the actual issue